# Comparar Dos Fechas DateTime en C#

Tags: c#

Hola amigos quiero comparar dos fecha `DateTime` en este formato `20/01/2019 09:00:00` , en la cual la comparación que estoy haciendo en linq que viene de una fecha de la base de datos del mismo formato y con otra que viene como parámetro:

```
fechaBaseDeDatos <= fechaParametro
```

Pero no me sale, alguna opcion?

Comment: ¿Cual es tu consulta?¿Cual es tu comparación? Agrega tu código para ayudarte sobre el.

Comment: Si ambas fechas son **de tipo** `DateTime`, la comparación debe funcionar. Estás seguro de que lo son? Que error te da la comparación?

Comment: Para que DateTime.Compare te regrese cero ambas fechas deben ser exactamente iguales incluso en cuanto a milisegundos, tal vez de ahí deriva tu error pues en tu primer ejemplo con fechaBaseDeDatos <= fechaParametro estás indicando que la expresión será verdadera si la fecha de base de datos es menor o igual a la fecha de parámetro y no si ambas fechas son idénticas.  Pero para entender mejor, deberías explicarnos la lógica de tu programa, ¿para qué necesitas comparar las fechas?

Comment: Si estas usando tipos de datos DateTime el formato no tiene nada que ver, porque un formato solo aplica en la visualizacion. Lo que si podrias hacer es usar el Sql Profiler para ver que sql esta generando el linq, porque puede que no tengas registros para el filtro que aplique. Quizas no es un tema del query sino de datos

Comment: podrías dar el resultado de lo que te da cada uno de las variables y que es lo que esperas obtener